# Bash script - new file belongs to the user with which the script was created

Tags: bash

I'm building a bash script that creates a log once is running but how can i make that the new file belongs to the user with which the script was created?

I tried using chown --reference without success

Comment: Show `chown` command you tried.

Comment: What do you mean "the user with which the script was created".  Didn't you create the script?

Comment: Are you asking for something like setuid scripts?

Comment: The chown command i usted was: chown --reference=file1 file2 the m qning of usted which created the file means if i'm user1 who created the script and user2 runs the script the file owner should ve user1  could you please Let me know More about setuid?